# creating a temporary entry to a model for rspec testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

i have a flash message in controller and i want to test it using rspec. 
In my controller i am setting a `flash[:notice]` if the database is empty otherwise it is nil.

```
def show
  if(User.first.nil?)
    flash[:notice] = "database is empty!"
  end
end
```

then in the rspec file i want to test both cases:
i: when `flash[:notice]` is set to "database is empty"
ii: when `flash[:notice]` is not set to anythin

```
def show
  it "assigns a "database is empty!" to flash[:notice]"
    expect(flash[:notice]).to eq("database is empty!")
  end

  it "does not assign anything to flash[:notice]"
    FactoryGirl.buil(:user)
    expect(flash[:notice]).to be_nil
  end
end
```

the first rspec test passes but the second one fails. i dont know how to assert that database is not empty for the second test case.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, but using the `factory-girl` incorrectly. There's method `build` (you have `buil` in the code) which initializes a record, but doesn't persist it (for example, it's like `User.new` with attributes).

To persist a record into a database, method `create` should be used, but before you actually make a request to `show`.

Something like the following (I don't know how the request is made, so `get :show` is just for example), using [`contexts`](http://www.betterspecs.org/#contexts), which allows you to separate tests into meaningful blocks:

```
context "request for the show on empty database" do
  before { get :show, params: { id: id } }

  it "assigns a 'database is empty!' to flash[:notice]"
    expect(flash[:notice]).to eq("database is empty!")
  end
end

context "request for the show on nonempty database" do
  before do
    FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    get :show, params: { id: id }
  end

  it "does not assign anything to flash[:notice]"
    expect(flash[:notice]).to be_nil
  end
end
```

Or specs can be separated into two blocks: one when database is empty, another when database is not empty (useful when you have multiple spec to be performed on empty/nonempty database)

```
context "when database is empty" do
  context "and show is requested" do
    before { get :show, params: { id: id } }

    it "flash[:notice] is assigned to 'database is empty!'"
      expect(flash[:notice]).to eq("database is empty!")
    end
  end
end

context "when database is not empty" do
  before { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  context "and show is requested" do

    before { get :show, params: { id: id } }

    it "does not assign anything to flash[:notice]"
      expect(flash[:notice]).to be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: does `before do` create the factory girl instance before each "it" blocks separately? if it does then the first test case will fail because if the database table is not empty then there will be no flash message.

Comment: yes, you need to separate it into another `context` block

Comment: could you please edit your answer and teach me about using context? what does context actually do?

Comment: `context` allows you to separate specs into meaningful blocks. updated

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're using `FactoryGirl.build` and not `FactoryGirl.create`.

When you use `build`, it creates a new instance of the model, but doesn't save it to the database, while `create` saves that instance in the db.

For more information, see here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#using-factories

Comment: but if i use create then the first rspec test fails the next time i run rspec command. because the first "it" tests if flash notice is set and it is only set when the database table is empty.